# AngularJS and Web Service Interaction Best Practices

Tags: c#, angularjs, web-services

I have a small website I implemented with AngularJS, C# and Entity Framework. The whole website is a Single Page Application and gets all of its data from one single C# web service.

[image]

My question deals with the interface that the C# web service should expose. For once, the service can provide the Entities in a RESTful way, providing them directly or as DTOs. The other approach would be that the web service returns an object for exactly one use case so that the AngularJS Controller only needs to invoke the web service once and can work with the responded model directly.

To clarify, please consider the following two snippets:

```
  // The service returns DTOs, but has to be invoked multiple 
  // times from the AngularJS controller
  public Order GetOrder(int orderId);
  public List<Ticket> GetTickets(int orderId);
```

And

```
  // The service returns the model directly
  public OrderOverview GetOrderAndTickets(int orderId);
```

While the first example exposes a RESTful interface and works with the resource metaphor, it has the huge drawback of only returning parts of the data. The second example returns an object tailored to the needs of the MVC controller, but can most likely only be used in one MVC controller. Also, a lot of mapping needs to be done for common fields in the second scenario.

I found that I did both things from time to time in my webservice and want to get some feedback about it. I do not care too much for performance, altough multiple requests are of course problematic and once they slow down the application too much, they need refactoring. What is the best way to design the web service interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise going with the REST approach, general purpose API design, rather than the single purpose remote procedure call (RPC) approach. While the RPC is going to be very quick at the beginning of your project, the number of end points usually become a liability when maintaining code. Now, if you are only ever going to have less than 20 types of server calls, I would say you can stick with this approach without getting bitten to badly. But if your project is going to live longer than a year, you'll probably end up with far more end points than 20.

With a rest based service, you can always add an optional parameter to describe child records said resource contains, and return them for the particular call.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with a RESTful service returning child entities or having an optional querystring param to toggle that behavior

`public OrderOverview GetOrder(int orderId, bool? includeTickets);`

When returning a ticket within an order, have each ticket contain a property referring to the URL endpoint of that particular ticket (/api/tickets/{id} or whatever) so the client can then work with the ticket independent of the order

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case I would say it depends on how many tickets you have. Let's say you were to add pagination for the tickets, would you want to be getting the Order every time you get the next set of tickets?

You could always make multiple requests and resolve all the promises at once via $q.all().

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to wrap up HTTP calls in an Angular Service, that multiple angular controllers can reference.

With that, I don't think 2 calls to the server is going to be a huge detriment to you.  And you won't have to alter the web service, or add any new angular services, when you want to add new views to your site.

Generally, API's should be written independently minded of what's consuming it.  If you're pressed for time and you're sure you'll never need to consume it from some other client piece, you could write it specifically for your web app.  But generally that's how it goes.